# Exception Problem when publishing ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a web application and when I decided to test on IIS 7 i have this Exception when trying to load a couple of pages that uses Entity Framework 4. I use EF 4 with my own CRUD assemblies but sometimes using the EntityDataSource. I have noticed that the problem is not appearing in all my Web Pages but I think in those that I use the EntityDataSource.

Here's the log from a Page:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

mscorlib

System.Type[] GetTypes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, ObjectItemCollection collection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ConstructContext()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
```

................it's not complete but I guess you can see the latest breadcumb...

Just for more info i post another page problem.

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

mscorlib

System.Type[] GetTypes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, ObjectItemCollection collection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ConstructContext()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.EnsureDataBound()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I think its the EDM problem but I can't get through.
I should mention that in my development pc is working all perfectly!!!

My controls are DevExpress but I dont think this should play any role!

Thank you.

[EDIT]

Thank you RD for edit.
Forgot to mention that I use Self tracking Template with the Entities.tt in a separate assembly!

[EDIT 2]

On my local Windows 7 IIS works OK! It's Windows Server 2008 I can't get it done!

Comment: Is your assembly with entities deployed?

Comment: Yes all assemblies are correct. I have Edited some info. Check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error as it seems that assemblies are not loaded. The app needed assemblies that I dont use into my application but I guess it searches using reflection. This had to do with DevExpress assemblies that I guess are referenced or loaded from reflection in another DevExpress assembly. The solution is to Log the LoaderExceptions and see what assembly u need.